# Responsive button images

Tags: html, css, wordpress-theming

this is my first post here. I am beginning my journey with css and html. I'm struggling with putting two responsive images next two each other that would act as buttons. What I am trying to get at is that all content is displayed on single page (without scrolling) and that the no matter the size of the screen it is always filled. Then with portrait mode on mobile screens it would display after each other.

This is how far I got already: http://test.fulfeal.co.uk/shop-intro/

I can't figure out whether it is to do with image size (the actual image is going to be a picture) or maybe with corresponding div sizes.

Thank you in advance for any help!

Answer (score 0):

In order for the images to take up the full page height, first make sure that you have the following:

```
html, body {
  height: 100%;
}
```

This will make sure your content can actually take up the full height of the page. Then, your images should also have their height set to 100%.

For the images to show up on top of each other for mobile, you'll need to use css media queries and then set the images to `display: block; width: 100%`.